# Wordpress get_the_term_list limit

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I am trying to display a product overview including their assigned categories. On the homepage we want to display a random overview of products but only show **one** of the categories assigned to avoid any clutter.
To show the categories, we use the following div.

Is there a way how we can limit the term to one? (Not the parent, but can be the one with the lowest ID or just random).

```
<div class="con"><?php echo get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'market', '', ',', '' ); ?></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get just one term, I would use:

```
<?php echo array_pop(get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'market'))->name; ?>
```

get_the_terms() returns an array of term objects for the given item, array_pop will get the last item of the array, and then we just want the name property from the object.

Comment: how to get the link of this taxonomy?